# Hyperthread behavior for omp applications windows 7 vs. centos

Tags: parallel-processing, openmp, utilization

I am trying to reconcile difference observed in the way that an omp code runs on two different systems with hyperthreading. System 1 is an Intel Xeon X5680 (12 physical processors/24 logical processors) with Centos 5.4. System 2 is is an Intel Xeon E5645 (6 physical processors/12 logical processors) with Windows 7.

The code is highly-parallelizable and will utilize each thread well.

I first ran the code on system 1 which demonstrated standard speedup with increasing threads until the number of threads exceeded the number of physical cores. After exceeding the number of physical cores, speedup became inconsistent and less than than the peak speed up I achieved using 12 threads. Initially, I found that behavior to make sense, assuming that 12 threads fully utilized 12 physical processors and that additional threads didnt help because the first 12 were fully utilizing the physical processors.

Then, I ran on system 2 which demonstrated speed up all the way up to 12 threads (twice the number of physical processors).  I found that puzzling because I expected speed up to stop when I had exceeded the number of physical processors. So, then I inspected a run with 6 threads and found that the each thread was limited to to half a physical processor--and that the only way to fully utilize the physical processors was start 12 threads.

So I think my question is, why does system 1 allow a single hyperthread to fully utilize a physical processor while system 2 restricts the hyperthread to 50% utilization of a physical processor? Perhaps this is a configuration option?

Thanks for your responses.

Comment: According to [X5680][1] have same cores and threads as of [E5645][2].
Clock speed is different so I suggest you to go through the architecture of both
[1]: http://ark.intel.com/products/48768/Intel-Xeon-Processor-E5645-12M-Cache-2_40-GHz-5_86-GTs-Intel-QPI 
[2] http://ark.intel.com/products/47916/Intel-Xeon-Processor-X5680-12M-Cache-3_33-GHz-6_40-GTs-Intel-QPI